# Generate object properties from values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to loop through some values and create object properties depending on said values. The reason for this is because I will be doing an insert query from a webpage that is dynamically generated so I don't know exactly what the properties would be.

I would like something along these lines. Obviously this does not work which is why I need some help.

```
$temp_arr = array();
$testing = $this->db->get('tblplatform_options')->row()->name;  //get possible values
foreach($testing as $test){
    array_push($temp_arr, "'".$test."' => $item['".$test."']");
}
$this->db->insert('tblitems_in', $temp_arr);
```

I already have a function that creates all the value fields in the database 'tblitems_in'. I just need a way to get the objects into that database.

**EDIT**

I found this example.

```
$propertiesToSet = array("var1" => "test value 1", 
                     "var2" => "test value 2", 
                     "var3" => "test value 3");
$myObject = new MyClass();
foreach($propertiesToSet as $property => $value) {
    // same as $myObject->var1 = "test value 1";
    $myObject->$property = value;
}
```

I am goinf to try something along the lines of.

```
$propertiesToSet = array("var1", "var2", "var3");
$myObject = new MyClass();
foreach($propertiesToSet as $property) {
    $myObject->$property;
}
```

Comment: what is $item? Is it some array?

Comment: $item is the object that i would like to add the properties to.

Comment: You need to follow the pattern in the example. What you are going to try will create the properties - but they won't have values.